# Filtering out nested objects by key: value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The object looks like this:

```json
{
    "msg": "OK",
    "blueprint": {
        "result": "OK",
        "blueprint": {
            "id": "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59",
            "product": {
                "productName": "Test Product",
                "productId": "AS_12-01",
                "description": "Test Descr.",
                "childProducts": [
                    {
                        "childId": "T1",
                        "parent": "8c59"
                    },
                    {
                        "childId": "T5",
                        "parent": "8c7e"
                    }
                ],
                "components": {
                    "component1": {         #
                        "compId": "C2",     #
                        "leadTime": 21,     # remove
                        "available": false  #
                    },
                    "component2": {
                        "compId": "C5",
                        "leadTime": 3,
                        "available": true
                    },
                    "component3": {         #
                        "compId": "C6",     # 
                        "leadTime": 12,     # remove
                        "available": false  # 
                    },
                    "component4": {
                        "compId": "C8",
                        "leadTime": 5,
                        "available": true
                    },
                }
            },
            "owner": "dummy",
            "name": "du_test"
        }
    }
}
```

How to remove marked components containing `"available": false` entries and return the object in the same form, just with those components left out?

I tried with filtering, but `components` is a key-value object, not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use `.filter()` after converting your `components` property values into an array using `Object.entries()`. Finally put everything back together with `Object.fromEntries()` and assign it to the result.

```js
const data = {'msg': 'OK', 'blueprint': {'result': 'OK', 'blueprint': {'id': 'a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59', 'product': {'productName': 'Test Product', 'productId': 'AS_12-01', 'description': 'Test Descr.', 'childProducts': [{'childId': 'T1', 'parent': '8c59'}, {'childId': 'T5', 'parent': '8c7e'} ], 'components': {'component1': {'compId': 'C2', 'leadTime': 21, 'available': false}, 'component2': {'compId': 'C5', 'leadTime': 3, 'available': true}, 'component3': {'compId': 'C6', 'leadTime': 12, 'available': false}, 'component4': {'compId': 'C8', 'leadTime': 5, 'available': true}}}, 'owner': 'dummy', 'name': 'du_test'}}};

data.blueprint.blueprint.product.components = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data.blueprint.blueprint.product.components).filter(([, value]) => value.available)
);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Ths is a smart one 

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

`Object.entries`, `Object.values`, `Object.keys`, `for..in`, `for..of` can be used to iterate through object

### Examples:

```js
const data = {
  "msg": "OK",
  "blueprint": {
    "result": "OK",
    "blueprint": {
      "id": "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59",
      "product": {
        "productName": "Test Product",
        "productId": "AS_12-01",
        "description": "Test Descr.",
        "childProducts": [{
            "childId": "T1",
            "parent": "8c59"
          },
          {
            "childId": "T5",
            "parent": "8c7e"
          }
        ],
        "components": {
          "component1": { //
            "compId": "C2", //
            "leadTime": 21, // remove
            "available": false //
          },
          "component2": {
            "compId": "C5",
            "leadTime": 3,
            "available": true
          },
          "component3": { //
            "compId": "C6", // 
            "leadTime": 12, // remove
            "available": false // 
          },
          "component4": {
            "compId": "C8",
            "leadTime": 5,
            "available": true
          },
        }
      },
      "owner": "dummy",
      "name": "du_test"
    }
  }
}

const changed = Object.entries(data.blueprint.blueprint.product.components).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (value.available) {
    acc[key] = value
  }
  return acc
}, {})

data.blueprint.blueprint.product.components = changed

console.log(data)
```

```js
const data = {
  "msg": "OK",
  "blueprint": {
    "result": "OK",
    "blueprint": {
      "id": "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59",
      "product": {
        "productName": "Test Product",
        "productId": "AS_12-01",
        "description": "Test Descr.",
        "childProducts": [{
            "childId": "T1",
            "parent": "8c59"
          },
          {
            "childId": "T5",
            "parent": "8c7e"
          }
        ],
        "components": {
          "component1": { //
            "compId": "C2", //
            "leadTime": 21, // remove
            "available": false //
          },
          "component2": {
            "compId": "C5",
            "leadTime": 3,
            "available": true
          },
          "component3": { //
            "compId": "C6", // 
            "leadTime": 12, // remove
            "available": false // 
          },
          "component4": {
            "compId": "C8",
            "leadTime": 5,
            "available": true
          },
        }
      },
      "owner": "dummy",
      "name": "du_test"
    }
  }
}

const {
  components
} = data.blueprint.blueprint.product

for (const key in components) {
  if (!components[key].available) {
    delete components[key]
  }
}


console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in an immutable manner, i.e. by creating a new structure without mutating the original one, then proceed like this:

```js
const obj = {"msg": "OK","blueprint": {"result": "OK","blueprint": {"id": "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59","product": {"productName": "Test Product","productId": "AS_12-01","description": "Test Descr.","childProducts": [{"childId": "T1","parent": "8c59"},{"childId": "T5","parent": "8c7e"}],"components": {"component1": {"compId": "C2","leadTime": 21,"available": false},"component2": {"compId": "C5","leadTime": 3,"available": true},"component3": {"compId": "C6","leadTime": 12,"available": false},"component4": {"compId": "C8","leadTime": 5,"available": true},}},"owner": "dummy","name": "du_test"}}}

const result = {
    ...obj,
    blueprint: {
        ...obj.blueprint,
        blueprint: {
            ...obj.blueprint.blueprint,
            product: {
                ...obj.blueprint.blueprint.product,
                components: {
                    ...Object.fromEntries(
                        Object.entries(obj.blueprint.blueprint.product.components).filter(([k, {available}]) =>
                            available
                        )
                   )
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
console.log(result);
```

As the structure is quite deep, you might want to have a function that gets the "path" to the object that needs filtering:

```js
function deepFilter(obj, ...args) {
    const [lastKey, filterKey, value] = args.splice(-3);
    const res = {...obj};
    const current = args.reduce((acc, key) => acc[key] = {...acc[key]}, res);
    current[lastKey] = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(current[lastKey])
              .filter(([, o]) => o[filterKey] === value)
    );
    return res;
}
 
const obj = {"msg": "OK","blueprint": {"result": "OK","blueprint": {"id": "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59","product": {"productName": "Test Product","productId": "AS_12-01","description": "Test Descr.","childProducts": [{"childId": "T1","parent": "8c59"},{"childId": "T5","parent": "8c7e"}],"components": {"component1": {"compId": "C2","leadTime": 21,"available": false},"component2": {"compId": "C5","leadTime": 3,"available": true},"component3": {"compId": "C6","leadTime": 12,"available": false},"component4": {"compId": "C8","leadTime": 5,"available": true},}},"owner": "dummy","name": "du_test"}}}
const result = deepFilter(obj, "blueprint", "blueprint", "product", "components", "available", true);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `Object.keys`

```js
const data = {
    "msg": "OK",
    "blueprint": {
        "result": "OK",
        "blueprint": {
            "id": "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59",
            "product": {
                "productName": "Test Product",
                "productId": "AS_12-01",
                "description": "Test Descr.",
                "childProducts": [
                    {
                        "childId": "T1",
                        "parent": "8c59"
                    },
                    {
                        "childId": "T5",
                        "parent": "8c7e"
                    }
                ],
                "components": {
                    "component1": {         
                        "compId": "C2",     
                        "leadTime": 21,     
                        "available": false  
                    },
                    "component2": {
                        "compId": "C5",
                        "leadTime": 3,
                        "available": true
                    },
                    "component3": {         
                        "compId": "C6",     
                        "leadTime": 12,     
                        "available": false
                    },
                    "component4": {
                        "compId": "C8",
                        "leadTime": 5,
                        "available": true
                    },
                }
            },
            "owner": "dummy",
            "name": "du_test"
        }
    }
};

const components = data.blueprint.blueprint.product.components;
Object.keys(components).forEach(key => {
  if (!components[key].available) delete components[key];
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {
    "msg": "OK",
    "blueprint": {
        "result": "OK",
        "blueprint": {
            "id": "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59",
            "product": {
                "productName": "Test Product",
                "productId": "AS_12-01",
                "description": "Test Descr.",
                "childProducts": [{
                        "childId": "T1",
                        "parent": "8c59"
                    },
                    {
                        "childId": "T5",
                        "parent": "8c7e"
                    }
                ],
                "components": {
                    "component1": {
                        "compId": "C2",
                        "leadTime": 21,
                        "available": false
                    },
                    "component2": {
                        "compId": "C5",
                        "leadTime": 3,
                        "available": true
                    },
                    "component3": {
                        "compId": "C6",
                        "leadTime": 12,
                        "available": false
                    },
                    "component4": {
                        "compId": "C8",
                        "leadTime": 5,
                        "available": true
                    },
                }
            },
            "owner": "dummy",
            "name": "du_test"
        }
    }
}

// console.log(a.blueprint.blueprint.product.components);

for (let key in a.blueprint.blueprint.product.components) {
    console.log(a.blueprint.blueprint.product.components[key])
    if (a.blueprint.blueprint.product.components[key].available === false) {
        delete a.blueprint.blueprint.product.components[key];
    }
};

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).